# Does Stash play nice with Search Fields plugin?

Tags: stash

I have Search Fields set up to do some non-standard filtering of a channel entry and all works fine. I've come across a separate issue where it would be good to derive a Stash list from these Search Field results but it doesn't seem possible to get the two working in tandem.

I realise that there's some overlap in terms of the functionality here but kind of reluctant due to time to abandon the current Search Fields setup - does anyone know of a way to set a Stash list from the SF results or is it a no go?